# How do I test a form submit in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, form-submit

I have a form that does some extensive Javascript stuff before finally POSTing to it's ACTION URL. I am writing some Jasmine unit tests and want to make sure the Javascript stuff happens when the form is submitted. However, I definitely don't want the page to go to the ACTION URL while I am unit testing.

I saw what seemed like a good suggestion here:
http://groups.google.com/group/jasmine-js/browse_thread/thread/a010eced8db17c1a?pli=1

...but, as I am fairly new to Jasmine, I am unsure how to implement it and cannot find any pertinent examples on the web. Does anyone have some sample code I could look at that would accomplish what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe this code snippet can help you...

```
it('calls ajax post on export button click', function() {
  view.render();
  var form = $('#export_images_xml_form');
  var submitCallback = jasmine.createSpy().andReturn(false);
  form.submit(submitCallback);

  $('#export_images_xml_button').click();

  expect(form.attr('action')).toEqual('/export');
  expect($('#export_images_xml_form input').attr('value')).toEqual('22,33,44');
  expect(submitCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

What I do is basically stopping every submit for given form returning false in the associated callback (see submitCallback behavior).

Then I can also test callback has been called...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Might me answers having 20 or more up votes should automatically be accepted, if there is no accepted ansers..:)

Comment: not sure if this is a version issue but the following had to be done for me
`jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(false)`

Comment: @peekabo, I'm getting "can't find variable view"

Comment: @peekabo Do we need to create fixtures for these elements? I'm getting undefined or unknown.

Comment: I am also wondering how to use the fixtures for this test, and wondering if you are using jasmine-query?  Where does view.render(); come from?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to test that `submit` was called, you don't need to create a spy. With plain jQuery, you can also attain the effect of not submitting the form. I put the following code outside of all tests, that way it applies to all tests within the file.

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I added `onsubmit="return false"` in the form tag