# How to test form .submit() with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, jasmine

I have method like that:

```
function submitMe() {
    if(someVal == true) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
}
```

I would like to test it with jasmine, but I really don't know how... I've found this answer: [How do I test a form submit in Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418217/how-do-i-test-a-form-submit-in-jasmine) but it looks like creating new form within test, and moreover this won't work...

I can't just spyOn(form, "submit"). I've tried spy on callback also...

Should I rewrite my code? I want to know, whether my form was submitted or not?

Answer (score 0):

The code in that answer doesn't create the form, it finds it by its id:

```
var form = $('#export_images_xml_form');
```

In your case, you should do:

```
var form = $('#myForm');
```

and then follow that solution and it should work.